# Why is cmss/m/it silently replaced by cmss/m/sl with T1, but warns with OT1?

Tags: font-encodings, italic, computer-modern, slanted

This is my MWE:

```
% \RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{lmodern}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\sffamily\textit{Hi!}

\sffamily\textit{Hi!}
\end{document}
```

It outputs a *warning*:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/sl' tried instead on input line 7.
```

So I added `fix-cm`, same thing. Also with `[OT1]{fontenc}`, with or without `fix-cm`, same thing. So replacing `cmss/m/it` by `cmss/m/sl` seems to be something to worthy of warning about.

So now I change back to `[T1]{fontenc}`, what I usually use (no `fix-cm` for now). The pdf output is basically the same - both variants still look exactly the same. But the warnings are completely gone, except for this *info*:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+cmss on input line 7.
```

If I add `fix-cm` back in, I at least get a more meaningful info:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/cmss/m/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/cmss/m/sl' tried instead on input line 7.
```

By the way, the situation is very similar with `lmodern`, with or without `fix-cm`, with `T1` or `OT1`:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/lmss/m/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/lmss/m/sl' tried instead on input line 7.
```

or

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/lmss/m/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/lmss/m/sl' tried instead on input line 7.
```

So what is it that makes replacing fonts so much more accepted with T1 (and with `lmodern`, apparently) than with OT1?

Comment: cm is not available in T1.  If you switch to T1 `cm-super` will be used.

Comment: @HenriMenke yes - I should have mentioned that I have `cm-super` installed.

Comment: I have opened a bug: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/172

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch to T1 encoding, LaTeX will load the `t1cmss.fd` font definition file, which contains the following line

```
\EC@family{T1}{cmss}{m}{sl}{ecsi}
```

That is to say, slanted `cmss` is simply remapped to `ecsi` (italic from cm-super), and since it is mapped you don't get a warning.

Comment: Yes, that is a technical explanation. Similarly, `fix-cm` does `\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmss}{m}{it}{<->ssub*cmss/m/sl}{}`, but nothing equivalent for `OT1`. I think my question is more about the motivation behind these differences.

Comment: How is this compatible why `T1/cmss/m/it` said to be not available?

Comment: @bers The motivation is probably a bug.

Comment: @HenriMenke -- I think it's a bit strong to say that the motivation is "probably a bug".  Very few sans serif fonts have a *designed* italic, with the differently shaped "a", "g", etc.  That leaves only the distinctive slope to differentiate slanted from upright.  I think it's probably just assumed that anyone serious about setting type should know this so it's not necessary to mention it.  (Maybe misguided, but understandable.)